# How broad is too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a problem understanding votings again.

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49572/how-to-challenge-epic-level-characters) is a question basically asking how to run an epic campaign.

[This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53260/how-to-build-an-evil-campaign) is a question basically asking how to run an evil campaign.

One was downvoted and closed. The other has 23 upvotes, not a single downvote and not a single close vote.

One of the points of critique for the first question was the lack of a specific version tag. Yet although the "great" question has a version tag, it's never used and the highly upvoted and accepted answer even says that it has *no experience in said tag* and just hopes that the general principles will be the same (and I do agree btw.).

So what exactly is the difference between the questions? Why is the "how to create an evil campaign" not "too broad"?

Answer (score 5):

Epic is more system dependent than evil, is the bottom line.

Comment: That's funny, because there's [five people here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53206/are-paladin-tenets-subjective/53208) supposedly telling me that evil is *very* system dependent in that very tag. Seems I cannot get it right no matter what I do.

Comment: @nvoigt the subtleties of alignment systems and what they mean for classes to whom alignments are important are both system dependent; the concept of running evil campaigns much less so (where it is generally "be the bad guys, and do the puppy kicking for a change").

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I hadn't looked at the evil campaign question. I've voted to close it as too broad myself, though I suspect that vote is unlikely to be taken up by others at this point. I think it's a pretty well-asked question (hence not downvoting), but I think it's too broad. That said, one major advantage it does have is that it mentions some of the characters involved, though only some of them and without much detail, so that wouldn't be enough to stave off my vote-to-close.

The epic campaign question actually looks *better* to me, though I'd still vote to close it as too broad. It gives several concrete ideas of the *problems* that you have run into and are trying to solve, which is good. But its hypothetical nature is a problem: you're not asking about a particular campaign, with particular characters and plot, but any epic-level game. That seems problematic to me, enough to close it and suggest you come back when you have an actual campaign.

Answer (score 2):

"Evil Campaign" is a *style* of campaign, while "Epic Campaign" is a *category* of campaigns. You may as well ask, "How to run a campaign that starts at level 1," or, "how to run a campaign that starts at level 11."

Epic only denotes the power level of the characters involved. It could still be heroic fantasy, or swords and sorcery, or wuxia, or mystery, or hack 'n slash, or any other number of things.

I'll admit that "Evil Campaign" is a fairly broad topic as well, but much less so. It denotes a specific type of campaign with a specific type of player character, and asks for specific help on the unique challenges that an evil campaign presents.

Going even further, you also didn't pick a specific version, which is important as the answer varies wildly based on the edition you're talking about. And then there are questions on exactly what level of epic you're playing, what level of optimization your players have (which is a huge factor in those levels, especially for 3.5), what classes they're playing, what type of players they are, etc.

I think you could either edit or re-ask your question, and be much more specific, and you'd get much better and more useful answers.